# Android VideoView stream playing is a mess

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player, android-mediaplayer

I am attempting to play a video from an http stream. I know the video is in the wrong format and encoded with an incomaptible codec, and also the resolution is too big, 640x380 I think.. but :

1. If I save the video on the SDCard and play it from there it works.
2. If I have only 3G connection, the video loads very slow... 30 sec - 1 minute... and than it starts to play!
3. If I am connected to a WiFi network I instantly get the message : "Sorry, this video is not valid for streaming on this device!"

Why the hell does it work when I'm connected through 3G !?
Anything would be appreciated, also if you have some links of valid videos that work on Android I would appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: At first I thought this wasn't a programming question. You might want to add more technical details. Are you getting any exceptions or interesting messages from LogCat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp
- http://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4

You may try those videos.